# Can I use OutputCache with more than one VaryBy for complex situations?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, outputcache

Can I do this?

```
[OutputCache(Duration = 111, VaryByParam = "id;category", VaryByCustom = "auth", VaryByHeader = "X-Requested-With")]
```

All these parameters will be used? 
Or will MVC just simply ignore all except VaryByCustom for example?

Answer (score 0):

All this `VaryBy*` can be used independently. And all used `VaryBy`* will work.